# Adding a new user to my AWS EC2, need to learn about .pub/.pem keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, pem

I'm trying to add a new user to a single EC2 instance, instead of giving access via IAM to the entire infrastructure.

Here's what I did so far:

```
ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f NewUser -t dsa
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
cat NewUser.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
chown NewUser .ssh
chown NewUser .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Great, now I'm trying to login myself to make sure it works before I pass the key to my colleague, however my SSH terminal asks me for a .PEM key (the private one). How do I download the private key? Placing the .pub obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key is called `NewUser`. It exists in the same folder as where you created `NewUser.pub`

[Here's some basic information on ssh keys from GitHub.](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) You can search for more.

Comment: Thank you very much, Tedder. 
It seems that all I missed was renaming the NewUser file to NewUser.pem so that my vSSH app would recognize it as a private key.